# MySQL alter table gives unknown column error

Tags: mysql, alter-table, alter

I'm renaming a bunch of columns in a lot of my tables and changing their data types for a major system update, and I haven't had many issues except for this one.

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'FactoryID' in 'factories'

```
show create table `factories`;
CREATE TABLE `factories` (
   `FactoryID` char(36) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
   `ParentFactoryID` char(36) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
   `Name` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
   `Notes` varchar(1024) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
   `DateTimeAdded` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
   `CountryID` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
   `ListID` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
   `Deleted` int(1) DEFAULT '0',
   PRIMARY KEY (`FactoryID`),
   UNIQUE KEY `FactoryID` (`FactoryID`),
   KEY `ParentFactoryID` (`ParentFactoryID`),
   KEY `CountryID` (`CountryID`),
   CONSTRAINT `factories[CountryID]` FOREIGN KEY (`CountryID`) REFERENCES `countries` (`CountryID`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

ALTER TABLE `sterling`.`factories` 
CHANGE COLUMN `CountryID` `CountryID` SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AFTER `FactoryID`,
CHANGE COLUMN `ParentFactoryID` `_OriginalFactoryID` CHAR(36) CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci' NULL DEFAULT NULL AFTER `ListID`,
CHANGE COLUMN `DateTimeAdded` `__Added` TIMESTAMP(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6) AFTER `__Active`,
CHANGE COLUMN `Deleted` `__Active` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1 ,
ADD COLUMN `__Updated` TIMESTAMP(6) NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6) AFTER `__Added`,
drop primary key,
change column`FactoryID` `@FactoryID`char(36)null after`__Updated`,
add column`FactoryID`binary(8)not null first,
add index`@FactoryID`(`@FactoryID`);
```

Am I missing an order of operations sort of thing? If all of those changes happen in order, I'm not sure what exactly the problem is, since at no time that `FactoryID` is referenced does it not exist.

Comment: Just splitting it after the `CHANGE COLUMN` into two alters worked, weird...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The columnname that `after` refers to is supposed to be the *new* name of the column in the final table. It doesn't matter where in the statement you change the name.

And it actually even makes this following statement fail:

```
alter table tablename
add column b int after a,
drop column a
```

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'a' in 'tablename'

as in the final table, there will be no column `a` anymore, so it is invalid even if you drop `a` only after you already added column `b`.

In your case, you would need to change

```
CHANGE COLUMN `CountryID` `CountryID` ... AFTER `FactoryID`,
```

to

```
CHANGE COLUMN `CountryID` `CountryID` ... AFTER `@FactoryID`,
```

in order to anticipate that you will (later) rename the column `FactoryID` to `@FactoryID`.

To make it complete: in `after`, you cannot refer to a column that you will `add` later. For example, in the end of your statement, you actually add another column `FactoryID`, but you cannot yet refer to it here (otherwise, the query would not have failed). You could add that column first though (and even before you rename the original `FactoryId`, MySQL allows you to swap columnnames that way). `CHANGE COLUMN CountryID CountryID ... AFTER FactoryID` would then work, but would refer to the *new* column (so in total, `CountryID` would be the 2nd column, which may or may not be what you intended).

I don't know if it is officially documented somewhere, you will probably have to take it as convention, but it has "always" been that way.

Comment: Yeah there is, ``add column`FactoryID`binary(8)not null first,``, that should add `FactoryID`, correct?

Comment: Just saw that edit, but yeah that's interesting that you can't refer to added columns

Comment: @BrianLeishman Added some more details for `add`. You can add it first if you want (even before renaming the existing column with the same name); `change column .. after factoryId` will then refer to this new column.